# How to select text in an EditText and keep it selected on screen?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, selection

I use EditText as a TextView because I need to highlight some certain part of text and EditText is doing it great. Now, if I want to share this highlighted quote with ActionBarSherlock's ShareActionProvider it goes well - I can pick this text from EditText.

But if a user longpress the text - he can highlight it any way he want. But the only option is to do something with that - for example, copy this selection and selection disappears after that. What I want is to freely highlight the text and then share highlighted text which should be keeped highlighted.

When you longpress the EditText you can select text, but any action like "copy" takes off selection and text is not highlighted